# How best to save image from camera for later processing?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, avfoundation

I'm getting an image from the camera using `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`.  I examine the pixelBuffer in my captureOutput:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
     didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
     fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection {

    CVImageBufferRef pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
```

If I find what I want in the pixelBuffer, then I want to save this image off for later image processing.

I see three options, and I am wondering which is the best to use:

1. I could save `sampleBuffer` or make a copy of it
2. I could save `pixelBuffer` or make a copy of it
3. I could make a `CGImage` from `pixelBuffer` and save that, and later when I need to do my image processing, I can use `CGBitmapContextGetData()` to get back a bitmap to operate on.  Seems like there's a bunch of unneeded copies here that I could do without.

Which one is the preferred way to save around the bitmap for later processing?  I don't need to save the bitmap for longer than a few minutes, i.e. no need to save to the filesystem.  If the answer is 1 or 2, then can I just retain the buffers or do I need to copy them by doing a `malloc` and `memcpy`?

Answer (score 0):

I do 3) but you must copy the pixel buffer into newly malloced memory as its only valid for the brief moment you are in that callback. I was grabbing 30 frames a sec using that technique.